# Custom IDs with PanacheMongoEntityBase does not work

Tags: mongodb, quarkus

I am trying to create a custom ID for my collection, always incrementing 1 to ID of the previous document. I am using MongoDB, Panache and Quarkus. My class looks like this:

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "order")
public class Order extends PanacheMongoEntityBase {


    @Id
    @BsonId
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "referenceNumberSequence",
            sequenceName = "referenceNumber_seq",
            allocationSize = 1,
            initialValue = 10000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "referenceNumberSequence")
    public Integer referenceNumber;
```

I would hope that when I call persist() on an order, it would generate the referenceNumber, starting at 10000 for the first document, but no referenceNumber is generated. Instead a ObjectId _id field is generated as normal, something I do not want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Id`, `@SequenceGenerator` and `@GeneratedValue` are JPA annotations. MongoDB with Panache is not a JPA implementation on top of MongoDB so you cannot use them.

If you want such feature, you need to implement it manually, for example by using a sequence collection with a unique document and incrementing this document for each new document on your order collection.

To explain why the _id field is generated as normal it's because your `referenceNumber` is null so MongoDB will generate a default id.